# Splitting strings in Oracle SQL by last white space before given index

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I'm using Oracle SQL and I have to split the company name field into 2 fields. The original field has a limit of 64 characters and new fields are going to be 32 characters long.

I don't want to do that by SUBSTR() as some of names would be splitted in ugly way. For example:

`Some Random Very Long Comapany Name Co. Ltd.` => `Some Random Very Long Comapany N` | `ame Co. Ltd.`

Is there any way to split it into a half using last white space before the 32nd character? For example:

`Some Random Very Long Comapany Name Co. Ltd.` => `Some Random Very Long Comapany` | `Name Co. Ltd.`

Comment: Combination of [INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF00651) and [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions196.htm#SQLRF06114) ?

Comment: There is a mismatch between your requirements (fields 32 characters long) and your suggested method (last space before the 32nd character) as when the 33rd character is a space then you can have a string exactly 32 characters long as the first substring. Also, if you need to split the string into a 29 character sub-string first then the second sub-string will be 34 characters long and will not fit in a 32 character field so you will need to split the string into 3 parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to split the words up into 3:

```sql
WITH bounds ( value, start_pos, end_pos ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         1,
         INSTR( SUBSTR( value, 1, 33 ), ' ', -1 )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         end_pos + 1,
         CASE
         WHEN LENGTH( value ) - end_pos <= 32
         THEN end_pos
         ELSE end_pos + INSTR( SUBSTR( value, end_pos + 1, 33 ), ' ', -1 )
         END
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_pos > start_pos
)
SELECT value,
       CASE
       WHEN end_pos < start_pos
       THEN SUBSTR( value, start_pos )
       ELSE SUBSTR( value, start_pos, end_pos - start_pos )
       END AS substring,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY value ORDER BY start_pos ) AS idx
FROM   bounds
ORDER BY value, idx;
```

Which for the sample data:

```sql
INSERT ALL
  INTO table_name VALUES ( 'This string is 32 charact. long. This string is 31 charac. long.' )
  INTO table_name VALUES ( 'This string is 31 charac. long. This string is 32 charact. long.' )
  INTO table_name VALUES ( 'This string is 30 chara. long. This string is 30 chara. long. 2c' )
  INTO table_name VALUES ( 'This string is 29 char. long. This string is 29 char. long. 4chr' )
  INTO table_name VALUES ( 'Some Random Very Long Comapany Name Co. Ltd.' )
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> VALUE                                                            | SUBSTRING                        | IDX
> :--------------------------------------------------------------- | :------------------------------- | --:
> Some Random Very Long Comapany Name Co. Ltd.                     | Some Random Very Long Comapany   |   1
> Some Random Very Long Comapany Name Co. Ltd.                     | Name Co. Ltd.                    |   2
> This string is 29 char. long. This string is 29 char. long. 4chr | This string is 29 char. long.    |   1
> This string is 29 char. long. This string is 29 char. long. 4chr | This string is 29 char. long.    |   2
> This string is 29 char. long. This string is 29 char. long. 4chr | 4chr                             |   3
> This string is 30 chara. long. This string is 30 chara. long. 2c | This string is 30 chara. long.   |   1
> This string is 30 chara. long. This string is 30 chara. long. 2c | This string is 30 chara. long.   |   2
> This string is 30 chara. long. This string is 30 chara. long. 2c | 2c                               |   3
> This string is 31 charac. long. This string is 32 charact. long. | This string is 31 charac. long.  |   1
> This string is 31 charac. long. This string is 32 charact. long. | This string is 32 charact. long. |   2
> This string is 32 charact. long. This string is 31 charac. long. | This string is 32 charact. long. |   1
> This string is 32 charact. long. This string is 31 charac. long. | This string is 31 charac. long.  |   2
> ```

---

## Update

> I'm aware of that I will only split those that second part after splitting will be no longer than 32, which is 90% of cases. Otherwise I will split it exactly in a half. Splitting into 3 fields is not possible in that case.

In light of the clarified requirements:

You can use:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN len - split_point <= 32
       THEN SUBSTR( value, 1, split_point - 1 )
       ELSE RTRIM( SUBSTR( value, 1, 32 ) )
       END AS first_substring,
       CASE
       WHEN len - split_point <= 32
       THEN SUBSTR( value, split_point + 1 )
       ELSE LTRIM( SUBSTR( value, 33 ) )
       END AS second_substring
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR( SUBSTR( value, 1, 33 ), ' ', -1 ) AS split_point,
         LENGTH( value ) AS len
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which, for the sample data above, outputs:

> ```
> FIRST_SUBSTRING                  | SECOND_SUBSTRING                
> :------------------------------- | :-------------------------------
> This string is 32 charact. long. | This string is 31 charac. long. 
> This string is 31 charac. long.  | This string is 32 charact. long.
> This string is 30 chara. long. T | his string is 30 chara. long. 2c
> This string is 29 char. long. Th | is string is 29 char. long. 4chr
> Some Random Very Long Comapany   | Name Co. Ltd.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0fec4f852a43d9c8799352295bf45851)*

Comment: I'm aware of that I will only split those that second part after splitting will be no longer than 32, which is 90% of cases. Otherwise I will split it exactly in a half.
Splitting into 3 fields is not possible in that case

Answer (score 2):

### Algorithm

You can use a combination of [INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564) and [SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm).

So the algorithm would be:

1. Get the substring of the original string (0 to half way)
2. Find the first space at the end of the half string (going backwards)
3. Split the original string at the point you found in 2.

### Implementation

You can get the cut-off point (character index) using: `INSTR(SUBSTR(company,1,32),' ',-1)` .
You could also use the reverse if you wanted (find the first space after the cut-off point).

### Full Implementation

```
select 

SUBSTR(company,1,
INSTR(SUBSTR(company,1,32),' ',-1)
)  as first32,

SUBSTR(company,
INSTR(SUBSTR(company,1,32),' ',-1)
)  as last32

from

(select 'Some Random Very Long Comapany Name Co. Ltd.' as company from dual)
```

### Update - trimming additional space

One solution is to add/remove 1 from the index:

```
select 

SUBSTR(company,1,
INSTR(SUBSTR(company,1,32),' ',-1)-1
)  as first32,

SUBSTR(company,
INSTR(SUBSTR(company,1,32),' ',-1)+1
)  as last32
```

Another option is to use the [LTRIM](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/ltrim.php) and [RTRIM](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rtrim.php) functions:

```
select 

RTRIM(SUBSTR(company,1,
INSTR(SUBSTR(company,1,32),' ',-1)
))  as first32,

LTRIM(SUBSTR(company,
INSTR(SUBSTR(company,1,32),' ',-1)
))  as last32
```

DbFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1d3149c51ee74b0cc97ffe2be819a882

Comment: Thank you. The result of that instruction has white space at the end of first `first32` and at the beginning of `last32`. What would be a good way to get rid of that?

Comment: @Fabian Using the trim functions and also modifying the index number by 1 number. Updated

Comment: @Fabian This doesn't work if there is a space in the 33rd character so that the first string can be exactly 32 characters long. Also, there are edge cases where you need to split the string into 3 parts (i.e. 29, 29 and 4 characters).

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . You can get the first part using:

```
regexp_replace(substr(name, 1, 32), '^(.* )[^ ]+$', '\1')
```

Then the second part is the "rest", which would be:

```
 substr(name, length(regexp_replace(substr(name, 1, 32), '^(.* )[^ ]+$', '\1')) + 1)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=94f1e2c7af8265ebca447fa9280473f5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: This doesn't work if there is a space in the 33rd character so that the first string can be exactly 32 characters long. Also, there are edge cases where you need to split the string into 3 parts (i.e. 29, 29 and 4 characters).